# How to get the result of the graphql refetchQueries?

Tags: redux, graphql, redux-saga, apollo-client

How can I get the result of refetchQuery in graphql,
after reading various issues and googling a lot I am not sure can we get the result of refetchQuery.
If not then how can I run my query after mutation more than once as the refetch query won't run if I again performing the same mutation?

and if there is a way to get the result of refetchQuery than how can I achieve it?

Comment: The `refetchQueries` option simply reruns queries in existing `Query` components. The refetched data is available in those particular components, so it's not necessary to somehow also return it. `refetchQueries` is not used to run a query after a mutation if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: As an aside, based on the question you deleted earlier, you should be using the available `Mutation` and `Query` components rather than trying to create your own. Their usage is well documented with plenty of examples and using the library as intended will generally lead to less unexpected behavior and less frustration for you, the developer.

Comment: Hi @DanielRearden thanks for your quick response, Can you tell me how can I run query after mutation without refetch as I tried to do so but it won't work at all

Comment: There's a couple of different ways to do that, but I suspect there may be easier ways of accomplishing whatever you are trying to do. Please edit your question with a better explanation of the expected behavior and sample code if possible.

Comment: Hi, @DanielRearden thanks for your suggestion I will keep that in mind and try to do so, also I have not deleted my earlier question, this is what I want aside from that.

Comment: Hi @DanielRearden, I think the issue is different then what I was trying to get, the thing is I am able to run the query after mutation without refetchQuery but it only the query once and if I again run the mutation the query just show me the previous result without refetching the data again, as aside from refetching again it is following every step so I think what I need is that I have to enable my query to not fetch the result from the cache but refetch it again from the server